# QT QStackedLayout problem

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt4

I would like to ask about QStackedLayout.
Now, I have a several widgets added to the QStackedLayout
And I want to do sth like that:
When user switch to Page X, refresh Page X.

How can I do that?
I have a custom code that I want to run when it refreshes
Thank You very much

Comment: What do you mean "refresh Page X"?

Comment: I mean load data again from database and show it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment to mine, it seems like you are looking for a signal that is generated when the current page changes so that you can update the underlying data for the screen. In that case, you would want to hook a slot up to [void QStackedWidget::currentChanged(int index)](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstackedwidget.html#currentChanged)

Comment: Yes, I have tried this.
connect(stackwidget,SIGNAL(currentChanged(int)),X,my slot(update_from_db));
But what should X be?  Thx

Comment: X would be a pointer to the object that implements the slot. and where you have "slot(update_from_db));" should be "SLOT(update_from_db(int)));"

Comment: I know it should be the  object that implements the slot

But I can't predict which object will be showed in the future
I tried this before, (ignore syntax)

for( all the widget window){    connect(stack,SIGNAL(currentchanged(int),widget,SLOT(update_db));
}

But it updates all the window widget rather than the widget that show.  Thx

Comment: The signal tells you what page of the stacked widget the user switched to. In the slot, you would query the DB for new info and then set values as appropriate on all the widgets for that page. The currentChanged is emitted by the stackedWidget, not by each widget on a page. I'm having trouble understanding your comments, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, let me explain it
First of all, all the widget in stack widget, I have implemented a function(or I can change it to slot) called update_db

I think X should be the widget that is on the top.
But it seems that I can never do it and here is my solution now
Now I make X is the MainWindow that contain the StackWidget and implement the slot switch_page.
In switch_page, I can use currentwidget to get the widget on the top. And I invoke the update_db of the widget

Is there a better method ? May be using slot

Comment: The update_db should be a method(slot) of your main window. In the constructor of your main window, you can call connect to connect the stacked widget's currentChanged() signal to your update_db slot. Use the index to determine which page widget is now on top, query the db for whatever info is being displayed there and then copy that data to any display widgets on the current page that need it.

Answer (score 2):

All "pages" are QWidget based classes. If your widgets does not paint itself properly you need to check your widget's code. Generally, while switching pages, visible widget repaint itself. If your widgets does not handle some events you can see glitches.

Anyway, if you want to force a repaint for your "page" you need to call [`QWidget::update()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#update) or (bruteforce method) [`QWidget::repaint()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#repaint).

Comment: +1. Note that `QWidget::repaint()` should _probably_ not be used. It's also unsafe if you're not careful, and might cause infinite recursion.

Comment: Sorry but no, you should not override update(). Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best way to handle this situation is through inheritance.  Create a class that derives from `QWidget` that has a virtual update function.  Use that as a base class for every page of your stacked widget.  In your class that contains the stacked widget, connect a slot to the [`currentChanged(int index)`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstackedwidget.html#currentChanged) signal of the stacked widget.  In that slot, get the current widget, [`qobject_cast`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qobject.html#qobject_cast) it to your base type, and (if successful) call the update function on it.

Each class that is a page in your stacked widget should then override the update function and use it to update its information as necessary.